# Node.js how do you console.log out an object-property + variable?

Tags: node.js, console.log, object-property

I am trying to console.log out an true / false statement by adding a variable to the end of the objectProperty to select the property: (appleAmount.amount+number)?
How do you do it?

```
let apple = 48;
let appleAmount = {
  amount0 : 20,
  amount1 : 40,
  amount2 : 48
}

let number = 2;
console.log(apple === appleAmount.amount+number);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can access properties by their string name, not just through the dot operator:

```
console.log(apple === appleAmount[`amount${number}`]); // If your version supports interpolation
console.log(apple === appleAmount['amount' + number]);
```

Comment: If your use case isn't much different, though, I would use an array instead of an object.

Comment: Thank you! Brett Beatty for the answer